# How to optimize multiple insert into wordpress database

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, sql

I had main file with my plugin and the another file with sql command. In the second file I create two tables and write data to one of them. But I have problem with. In my private computer everything works good but on external server not. How can I optimize command below I have a 700 pieces insert like this:

```
$wpdb->insert( 
    $ow_table_adres, 
    array( 
        'id' => '', 
        'address' => 'test', 
        'kod' => '096-024', 
        'number' => '4'
    ) 
);
```

Comment: What fails? How does it fail? Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? What do your server logs say? I routinely run queries like that (with `$wpdb->query` not `$wpdb->insert`, which is helper function overload but that is beside the point) with no issue. I am pretty sure this is specific to your server, and I am guessing it is a timeout.

Answer (score 3):

To optimize the query, instead of use `$wpdb->insert` is possible to use `$wpdb->query` and use a single query that insert all the items.

In fact, according to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html):

> If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time,
>   use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several
>   rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some
>   cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements

So, if you have an array `$all_items` where every array item is an array having 'address', 'kod' and 'number' items, something like:

```
$all_items = array(

  array( 'address' => 'test', 'kod' => '096-024', 'number' => '4' ), 

  array( 'address' => 'test2', 'kod' => '096-025', 'number' => '5' ), 

  array( 'address' => 'test3', 'kod' => '096-026', 'number' => '6' ),  

);
```

then you can

```
$q = "INSERT INTO $ow_table_adres (address, kod, number) VALUES ";

foreach ( $all_items as $an_item ) {
  $q .= $wpdb->prepare(
    "(%s, %s, %d),",
    $an_item['address'], $an_item['kod'], $an_item['number']
  );
}

$q = rtrim( $q, ',' ) . ';';

$wpdb->query( $q );
```

Comment: Can you also add this array to solution ?

Comment: Can you write how should be look this array $all_items for many row ?

Comment: @PrzemysławSuszek added.